# How to pinch in zoom an image in ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I have a made a full image viewer modal in ionic 4 app, but in modal i want to zoom in image on pinch on the image , How can i do this with suitable plugin or without plugin?

Comment: check this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-img-viewer

Comment: Implemented this but this is not working :/

Comment: ngx-pinch-zoom works well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pinch-zoom

Comment: Thanks A Ton @DeWetvanAs It is working awesome

Answer (score 7):

In the view:

```
<ion-slides [options]="sliderOpt" zoom>
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
       <img src="ubication" /> // Replace here
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In TS:

```
sliderOpt = {
  zoom: {
    maxRatio: 1,
  },
};
```

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_MFYvZxJ0E